# Stubborn system file will not budge from the end of drive, cannot shrink partition

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, defragment, boot-partition

I'm trying to shrink my Windows 7 partition on my 400GB HDD down to about 200GB to dual boot Ubuntu, and I have consolidated all my data and defragged a number of times with different programs (PD12, Auslogics, Acronis DD), including before Windows boots up, and I just cannot get this one system file to budge. Here's a picture of the current drive map:

[image]

The orange box at the bottom is the file system.workflowservices.ni.dll. I'm unable to uninstall it and I'm really at a loss here. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

How about backing up your system, shrink the drive, then restore.  Worst case, nuke the drive and repartition it, then restore your backup.